# Is there a way to force Babel to preserve whitespace?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, babeljs

I like to keep everything look squarely when I write my code, and Babel is giving me a hard time :(

```
const describe = require("mocha").describe;
const it       = require("mocha").it;
```

becomes

```
const describe = require("mocha").describe;
const it = require("mocha").it;
```

I am using Babel with Grunt and tried the `retainLines` option, which sadly only preserves newlines (and even then, not exactly as the original).

Is there any option for Babel to preserve whitespace?